# SQL append multiple tables when a part of the name is

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know, whether it is possible to append queries after one and other, based on a part of the table name. Our SQL server is build up into country based databases, meaning that each country has its own database. For each country there is also a store, in which we name the store by postal code and the name of the store. All of the tables concerning that specific store start with the postal code and name, followed by a "$" and afterward the table name will come.

Lets say the first part of the name is "NO6800 Store1$" which is the dynamic part.
After that the table will be named "Sales Invoice Header", which is the same for all stores.

My question is, if I'm able to get SQL to find all of the tables, which contains the value "Sales Invoice Header" and append all of the queries into one automatically. If possible it would be great, if I can get it across the country databases.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle, MySQL,SQL Server etc.,?

Comment: An important detail i left out... Ooops. It is Microsoft SQL Server. I would just like to make a query within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Comment: Is Sql Server?.. MySQL??.......

Comment: With this you can find the structure SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy SQL Server 12.0.6214.1

Comment: Ok What you mean by append into one? can you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: By append into one I mean "union all".

Comment: Are you seriously saying you have a table named `NO6800 Store1$Sales Invoice Header`? If so, honestly, I recommend a rethink on your naming structure.

Comment: @Larnu When I go to the SQL Server in Management Studio, I can press Databases --> Norway --> Tables --> NO6800 Store1$Sales Invoice Header. But by referencing to sys.tables it doesn't come up. sys.tables does only show 5 tables, which has nothing to do with any store what so ever. Therefore I cannot find it in sys.tables. But manually expanding the "Tables" folder I can find it and click "Select top 1000 rows".

Comment: Sounds like your querying `sys.tables` in the wrong database, @PatrickS, but like i said, `NO6800 Store1$Sales Invoice Header` is a terrible name for any object in SQL Server. You should try to keep names succinct, and not require you to delimit identify them.

Comment: @Larnu Now I can get all of them to show. cross country, just by selecting everything from sys.tables and removing the step with the database first.

Comment: So, let me understand this correctly, you want to union all the tables together, **in different databases**, that end in the name `Sales Invoice Header`? Or are all the tables in 1 database?

Comment: Is this assumption correct, @PatrickS ? If so, this really infers you need to redesign your entire instance; not just your databases.

Answer (score 0):

Look into querying the `sys.databases` and `sys.tables` system tables. They contain a `name` column that you can query with a normal `LIKE` query to find databases...

Example:

```
select * from sys.databases where name LIKE '%Norway'

select * from sys.tables where name LIKE '%Sales Invoice Header'
```

Comment: sys.tables doesn't show the table I'm looking for, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.

You need to identify all table names (Assuming they have the same structure), then build a CTE query that has the WITH part select statements from each table united with union all, followed by the final query that you need to run across all tables which will target the CTE.

For Example:

```
WITH CrossCountry_CTE (Col1, Col2, ColN)  
AS  
-- Define the CTE query.  
(  
    SELECT Col1, Col2, ColN FROM NO6800Store1$SalesInvoiceHeader
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Col1, Col2, ColN FROM XX0000StoreU$SalesInvoiceHeader
    UNION ALL
    ..
    SELECT Col1, Col2, ColN FROM YY0000StoreV$SalesInvoiceHeader
)  
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name. Random query here:
SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) AS TotalSales, ColN
FROM CrossCountry_CTE
GROUP BY ColN, Col1
ORDER BY Col1, ColN;
```